# On scroll load more data from database not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I trie to load more data on scroll to the bottom. All works fine in Edge,Chrome,Firefox but not in IE 11. Nothing happens there

Here's my Code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) {
        if (timer) {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            // Magic goes here
        }, 400);
    }
});
```

Meta Tag is set to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Many thx

**EDIT**

If i open the debug mode on IE , everything works fine. No errors

Comment: Can you share the full code? or at least a version we can use? In your code, the `setTimeout` doesn't have a delay for example, is it on purpose?

Comment: I also made a test with this code. https://textuploader.com/1sn05 and code is working fine with IE 11. Here is a testing result. https://i.postimg.cc/L6FBk482/6.gif Looks like something else causing this issue. I suggest you to make a test on any other machine with IE11 to check whether on that machine your code is working or not. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your code example on IE11 and works perfectly fine. Here is the test code i ran in the browser:

```
var timer;

$(window).scroll(function(){        
    if ($(document).height() <= $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) {
        if(timer) {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            alert('bottom of page');
         });
     }
});
```

Are there any errors thrown in your console on IE11? Sharing more of the code in question would help, as there is no inherent reason for the example you have given to not work on IE11.